# How to design Python code for easy addons/customization by third persons

Tags: python, unit-testing, architecture, frameworks

I'm testing HW & SW at the moment. To follow our process I need to prepare a "test scenario specification" and "test case specification documents" and based on "test case spec" prepare a testing script/code to verify the HW and SW.

Example of test scenario spec:
[image: Test scenario specification example]

Example of test case spec:

[image: Test case specification example]

During coding/testing I've figured out that we need to update the "test scenario" & "test case" specs. This is error prone. Another point is, once you update one document, you are forced to update the remaining documents.

So I came up with an idea to create a framework to simplify my life and write everything in Python. I need to comment my code anyway, so I would use the source code, it's comments, description etc. to generate the documentation.

**Brief architecture description:**
Test Framework class - holds 0 - x test scenarios
Test Scenario class - holds 0 - x test cases
Test Case class - holds 0 - x test steps
Test Step class - this class represents a single step to be performed as  described in the test case spec.

I've decided to use a class for the step as I need to hold information about the expected result + I need to store the actual result after test execution and I need to have access to those variables for every step.

All the stuff (Framework, scenario, test case) should be unchanged and generic for every testing, however, the "Test steps" carried out for every test case differ and are added based on needs etc. So this code can be considered as third party/person code or so which is not part of the framework.

**The question is, how to design such thing? Code which needs to be added.**

I came up with the following architecture:
1) Using construtor create test scenario instance
2) call append test case method
 - this method requires/expects a module name
 - the user creates a new module (new file.py) per test case

3) the append method with given module imports the module and reads/stores it's internals - name, description, steps.

4) The user creates a Framework instance which contains methods for iterating over all registered scenarios and test cases and runs all the tests automatically etc.

5) The user must register the scenario.

**Module Structure:**

```
    name = "Undervoltage simulation during stop mode"
    description = "This test verifies undervoltage during stop mode..."

    #The user defines a single method for every step:
    def step1(*args, **kwargs):
       ...

    def step2(*args, **kwargs):
       ...
```

Code snippet:

```
    import tfw
    import tscenario
    import tcase
    import tstep

    test_setup = tfw.TestFramework()

    ts1 = tscenario.TScenario('TS0003', 'Requirement1', 'WPT undervoltage simulation')
    ts1.append_test_case('test_case_module_1')

    ts2 = tscenario.TScenario('TS0004', 'Requirement2', 'WPT overvoltage simulation')
    ts2.append_test_case('test_case_module_2')

    test_setup.register_scenarios([ts1, ts2])

    test_setup.generate_scenario_spec('C:/Test/wch65w_test_scenario_spec.xlsx')
    test_setup.generate_test_case_spec('C:/Test/wch65w_test_case_spec.xlsx')

    test_setup.execute()
```

Everything works as expected, however, I don't have a good feeling about the design - this is the right way how to do it.

I don't won't to bother the user with stuff like create a "Test step" object for every step you want to perform, put it into a list, this is your input into the append_test_case() method etc. I would like to abstract away the user from these things.

However, this is the only thing I came up with. I'm also a beginner with Python, so I don't have many experiences with all the concepts Python offers.

Thank you for your hints and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for those cases where non-technical people are involved in the process of testing is that Behavior-driven development (or BDD) exists.

I recommend you to look to [Behave](https://github.com/behave/behave), which is for me the testing library that has the better BDD implementation out there. From their Github project description:

> Behavior-driven development (or BDD) is an agile software development
>   technique that **encourages collaboration between** developers, **QA** and
>   **non-technical or business participants** in a software project.

Behave uses feature files where is documented how a software should work. The non-technical persons in your team are supposed to write this specification. I going to add a very simple example:

```
Feature: Supported voltage

  Scenario: Plug a device in a 110 socket
    Given we have a device
     When we plug it into a 110 socket
     Then the devices does not explode

  Scenario: Plug a device in a 220 socket
    Given we have a device
     When we plug it into a 220 socket
     Then the device dies miserably
```

The **given**, **when** and **then** lines are called steps, and you can associate each of them to a Python function which must test that the defined statement are correct.

```
from behave import given, when, then, step

@given('we have a device')
def setup_device(context):
    pass

@when('we plug it into a {voltage:d} socket')
def plug_to_socket(context, voltage):
   # your code

@then('behave will test them for us!')
def step_impl(context):
    # test what happens
```

Note the second function **`plug_to_socket`**, it can handle dynamically the steps `When we plug it into a 110 socket` and `When we plug it into a 220 socket` because it defines a variable **`voltage`**, which can take an integer.

So this library can help you avoid duplicated code and create a flexible framework where the non-technical people can define how the product (SW/HW) should work.

I can not help much because I am not aware of the business logic of your software so I can't put a better example. But I think this is a starting point and you must read the documentation of Behave to familiarize with it.

Comment: Hi miso, thanks for your post, although it doesn't answer my question directly. :-) I'll definitely have a look at Behave to not to reinvent the wheel. Possibly this is the way to go.
The framework itself is for technical persons. I would like ease my and others life from preparing several different documents and maintain just a single source code with a framework in background.